# converting string into a tuple

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7, tuples

My goal is to convert a string into a tuple

Currently, I have a string that is surround by parentheses with its contents separated by commas.

```
>>>'1, 4, 1994' (variable name birthday)
(1, 4, 1994) # desired output
```

I have been trying to use split() to convert the string into tuple, but

```
tuple(birthday.split())
('1,', '4,', '1994')
```

but the contents are surrounded by subsequent parentheses.

What pythonic methods can I use to make the conversion?

Comment: I think one main thing here is that you need to split on the comma

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this,

```
In [35]: tuple(map(int,birthday.split(',')))
Out[35]: (1, 4, 1994)
```

Problem with your spit function. Use `,` to split.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `str` to `int` and specify a `sep` argument for [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
res = tuple(map(int, '1, 4, 1994'.split(', ')))  # (1, 4, 1994)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = '1, 4, 1994'
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> (1,4,1994)
```